# Kill python process with pkill python

Tags: python, bash, shell

i want to stop python process in a script, but in the first time i don't have any process running but i should pass with my function restart :

```
function restart() {
   stop
   start
}
function start (){
exec ./server --db_host=.......
} 
function stop (){
pkill python
}
```

the problem is when i execute restart its blocked, so can you suggest me how to have a control like this

```
if [i have python process runing];then pkill python
```

thanks

Comment: It's not clear why you want to do the `if` check? pkill won't write anything to stderr if there are no python process, so `restart` or the other two commands will execute without any issues. Unless you want to check for stopped processes or something weird, in which case you will need to read /proc/pid/state or something similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick

```
if [ `ps -e | grep python | wc -l` -gt 1 ]
then
    pkill python
if
```